# Android Navigation drawer で画面を切り替え、画面にタブを使用したい

Tags: android

[GooglePlayストア]　アプリでは、NavigationDrawerで画面を切り替えて、かつ切り替わった画面にタブが使用されてますよね。
例）ドロワー　→　マイアプリ　→　インストール済み、全て(←ここ)
これを自分のアプリでも実現するするにはどうすれよいか、分かる方いらっしゃいますか？

実現したいのはNavigationDrawerで画面を切り替え、画面内にタブを使用することです。

Answer (score 3):

> NavigationDrawerで画面を切り替え

公式のHandle Navigation Click Eventsに、Fragmentの切り換えで実現する方法が紹介されています。

http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks

> 画面内にタブを使用する

Playストアアプリのタブは（おそらく）ViewPager + PagerTitleStripで実現されていると思います。

http://qiita.com/mackiso/items/1dacec44d9096bc6d900

Answer (score 1):

最新のAndroid Studioの新規プロジェクト作成時のテンプレートに
「Navigation Drawer Activity」
というものがあるので、それをもとに作成すればNavigationDrawerでのFragment切り替えは
容易に作成できます。

NavigationDrawer内でのタブの表示はfkmさんが仰られている通りViewPager + PagerTitleStrip
かと思われます。

Android5.0よりsetNavigationModeが非推奨となったので
今後のタブ実装はこのような形が主流となりそうです。